# xhtmlrenderer creating PDFs of length 0

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I am new to `org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer` and have this problem:

The PDFs that my test servlet streams to my Downloads folder are in fact empty files.

The relevant method, `streamAndDeleteTheClob`, is shown below.

The first try block is definitely not a problem.

The server spends a lot of time in the second try block. No exception thrown.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem or a good approach to to debugging it?

Can anyone point me to essentially similar code that really works?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
res.setContentType("application/pdf");

ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();

...

private boolean streamAndDeleteTheClob(int pageid,
                                  Connection con,
                                  ServletOutputStream out) throws IOException, ServletException {
   Statement statement;

   Clob htmlpage;

   StringBuffer pdfbuf = new StringBuffer();

   final String pageToSendQuery = "SELECT text FROM page WHERE pageid = " + pageid;

   // create xhtml file as a CLOB (Oracle large character object) and stream it into StringBuffer pdfbuf

  try {  // definitely no problem in this block
    statement = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(pageToSendQuery);
    if (resultSet.next()) {
      htmlpage = resultSet.getClob(1);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    final Reader in = htmlpage.getCharacterStream();
    final char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    while ((in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      pdfbuf.append(buffer);
    }            
  } catch (Exception ex) {       
    out.println("buffering CLOB failed: " + ex);
  }

  // create pdf from StringBuffer

  try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(pdfbuf.toString())));
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(out);
    out.close();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    out.println("streaming of pdf failed: " + ex);

  }

  deleteClob(con, pageid);

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the DocumentBuilder.parse this way will try to resolve the DTD referenced in the XHTML page. It takes a really long time. The easyest way to aviod that if you are using the Flying Saucer (xhtmlrenderer), is to create the document this way:

```
Document myDocument = XMLResource.load(myInputStream).getDocument();
```

Note that you can use XMLResource.load with a Reader too.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly a cause of the problem. Stumbled on it myself, googled the answer, everything works.

Comment: do you remember what kind of times you're getting? With these optimizations FS takes about 300 ms still to render a page which isn't horrible, but not that great, especially because the HTML is minimal

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of.

1) If the iText document is not closed, it'll be empty.  Looks like `renderer.finish()` will work, but `createPDF(out)` *should* do that already.

2) If there are no pages, you could get an empty doc as well... so an empty input could result in a 0-byte PDF.

3) You might be getting a perfectly valid PDF that's not being streamed properly.  Try writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream and checking the length there.

4) An almost fanatical dedication to the Pope!